# Unable to get selected value of dropdown in angular controller on its change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

I tried all of the way I found but it's not working, I am just simply trying to get selected option of a dropdown on its change event in angular js way so that it would be passed to the ajax and fetch the data from database. I have angular.min.js 1.4.8 version cdn in my project.

I copy/paste my code into plunker there its working fine but while running my project in browser its not working. Below is my JS and html code snippet.

**JS Code**

```
$scope.inputs = [{
    id : 1,
    name : 'option1',
    value : 'option1',
    inputType : 'tag',
    valueOperator : "option1Operator",
    operatorType : 'operatorType1'
    }, {
    id : 2,
    name : 'option2',
    value : 'option2',
    inputType : 'text',
    valueOperator : "option2Operator",
    operatorType : 'operatorType1'
    }];
$scope.inputSelectedChange = function(){
        $scope.$watch('inputSelected',function( val ){
               $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: '<<URL>>',
                  responseType: 'json',
                  params:{inputName: "prdSeqId"}
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                     //something
}, function errorCallback(response) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                  });
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<select ng-model="inputSelected" 
        ng-options="input as input.name for input in inputs" 
        ng-change="inputSelectedChange()" required>
    <option value="">Select Input</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You don't have to use $scope.$watch for your ng-change function because the ng-model value will be available in your controller

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: n-model value is undefined with or without $scope.$watch, I tried both the way. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console ? Check the answer below and try to recreate the same code @RohitMishra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //html
 <select ng-model="inputSelected" id="inputSelected" class="form-control positionTypes" ng-options="input as input.name for input in inputs" ng-change="inputSelectedChange(inputSelected)" required>
     <option value="">Select Input</option>
 </select>

//controller
$scope.inputSelectedChange = function(value){
  console.log(value)
};
```

Comment: I was passing in ng-change name other than inputSelected, Silly mistake.. Thankyou so much for your solution.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try changing function like below:
and get value.

```
$scope.inputSelectedChange = function(){
  console.log($scope.inputSelected)
  //do other stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of selected item inside `ng-change` from `ng-model`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.inputs = [{
    id : 1,
    name : 'option1',
    value : 'option1',
    inputType : 'tag',
    valueOperator : "option1Operator",
    operatorType : 'operatorType1'
    }, {
    id : 2,
    name : 'option2',
    value : 'option2',
    inputType : 'text',
    valueOperator : "option2Operator",
    operatorType : 'operatorType1'
    }];
$scope.inputSelectedChange = function(){
console.log($scope.inputSelected)
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select ng-model="inputSelected" id="inputSelected" class="form-control positionTypes" ng-options="input as input.name for input in inputs" ng-change="inputSelectedChange()" required>
    <option value="">Select Input</option>
</select>
</div>
```